# Trigger error on update

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TRIGGER `update_hidden` AFTER UPDATE ON boutique
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
         UPDATE `items` SET hidden = NEW.hidden WHERE boutique_id = NEW.id;
    END
```

I have a table boutique and table items, both have field `hidden`, after executing this code i get a syntax error, what is my mistake?

Comment: after changing the value hidden of the boutique table, all the children whos boutique_id = boutique.id items will have the same value on hidden field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove spaces between ROW BEGIN:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `update_hidden` AFTER UPDATE ON boutique
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
         UPDATE `items` SET hidden = NEW.hidden WHERE boutique_id = NEW.id;
    END
```

Comment: Fixed, i've just changed the delimiter in phpmyadmin, thanks!